# How to add title page image in apache poi with header image in it. Currently, whenever I add image in header, title page image disappears

Tags: java, image, apache-poi, xwpf

Here I am trying to insert image in the title page in apache poi but with the header image, it is not displaying the image on the title page. If I remove the addPicture from the header part, then, title page correctly displays the proper image. I am not sure what's the issue. I have added the code here.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.HeaderFooterType;

public class Check {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

        XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

        CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        sectPr.addNewTitlePg();

        File image = new File("D:\\Img.png");
        FileInputStream imageData = new FileInputStream(image);

        run = paragraph.createRun();
        int imageType = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG;
        String imageFileName = image.getName();

        int width = 612;
        int height = 550;

        run.addPicture(imageData, imageType, imageFileName, Units.toEMU(width), Units.toEMU(height));
        paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("The Body... first page");

        paragraph = document.createParagraph();
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
        run.setText("The Body... second page");

        XWPFHeader header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.FIRST);
        paragraph = header.createParagraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
        run = paragraph.createRun();
        run.setText("First page footer...");
        
        
        // adding header here
        header = document.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);

        paragraph = header.getParagraphArray(0);
        if (paragraph == null)
            paragraph = header.createParagraph();
        paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
        image = new File("D:\\Picture.png");
        imageData = new FileInputStream(image);

        run = paragraph.createRun();
        imageType = XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG;
        imageFileName = image.getName();

        width = 100;
        height = 50;
        // adding image here.
        run.addPicture(imageData, imageType, imageFileName, Units.toEMU(width), Units.toEMU(height));

        // header image part completed
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\CreateWordFooters.docx");
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
        document.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: What `apache poi` version are you using?

Comment: I am using 4.1.1.

Comment: Cannot reproducing that issue. Exactly your code works for me using `apache poi 4.1.1`. Result is a document having a big picture on first page and a small picture in default header.

Comment: Not sure, but this is not working for me anyhow. Can you please share the document you have created anywhere? Are you using the similar code?

Comment: Used exactly your code. Of course I have used different image files. It creates https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Dic_hD-F4XzXhkJu2qRXK0TZhsA9TjfmL1mSR36uHmQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's really working at your end. What version of java you are using? I am using java 8. I am not sure if it is the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239908/discussion-between-kiran-gavhane-and-axel-richter).